# how to read a single number as a single character at a time not alphabets

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I'm doing the accessibility, where I have a address eg :3156 Stock Avenue Ln B, Stockland, CA 95209. Where I want it to read only digits one at a time means a single character and read the address as it is.
How can I define in Java.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried just separating the number with spaces? textView.setContentDescription("3 1 5 6 Stock Avenue Ln B, Stockland, CA 9 5 2 0 9");

Comment: Be careful here. Screen reader users are already accustomed to addresses and zip codes being read the way they are. If you break them up into numbers make sure you understand how it impacts SR users (speed, pronunciation, ability to copy, consistency with other apps they use on their phone, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
 public static String ExtractNumberFromString(String cnvrtdDate){
        String [] dateArray = cnvrtdDate.split("|");
        //System.out.println(dateArray);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<dateArray.length;i++)
        {
            boolean ItIs = isNumeric(dateArray[i]);
            if(ItIs)
            {

                sb.append(dateArray[i]);
            }

        }
        return  sb.toString();
    }
```

**Also, to check number:**

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  {
    try
    {
        int d = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    catch(Exception nfe)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: where r u defining the d in this statement ( int d = Integer.parseInt(str);).

Comment: Appreciate yr help

Comment: its just a variable, to check it is Char or Number, just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just extract numbers from a string you also can use Java 8 features:

```
String result = string.chars().filter(Character::isDigit)
.collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, i) -> sb.append((char) i), append)
.toString();
```